# When values are being written to google sheets from the nodemcu, the heart beat sensor (MAX30100) does not read values. How can I fix this error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, arduino, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I am setting up a device which will monitor the temperature and heartbeat of a person. The temperature and heartbeat values are instantly uploaded to google sheets using a script. The temperature values work fine, but the heartbeat values show 0. When I run the code without uploading data, the vales work fine in the Arduino serial plotter.

All values obtained when displayed on Arduino serial plotter. But unfortunately, when using the postData() the heartbeat values show 0.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "HTTPSRedirect.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS     1000

PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;

const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

// The ID below comes from Google Sheets.
// Towards the bottom of this page, it will explain how this can be obtained
const char *GScriptId = "gscriptid";

// Push data on this interval
//const int dataPostDelay = 900000;  // 15 minutes = 15 * 60 * 1000

const char* host = "script.google.com";
const char* googleRedirHost = "script.googleusercontent.com";

const int httpsPort =  443;
HTTPSRedirect client(httpsPort);

// Prepare the url (without the varying data)
//String url = String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?";

const char* fingerprint = "some fingerprint";

// We will take analog input from A0 pin 
const int AnalogIn     = A0; 

// Callback (registered below) fired when a pulse is detected
void onBeatDetected()
{
  Serial.println("Beat!");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Connecting to wifi: ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.flush();

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


  Serial.print(String("Connecting to "));
  Serial.println(host);

  bool flag = false;
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    int retval = client.connect(host, httpsPort);
    if (retval == 1) {
       flag = true;
       break;
    }
    else
      Serial.println("Connection failed. Retrying...");
  }

  // Connection Status, 1 = Connected, 0 is not.
  Serial.println("Connection Status: " + String(client.connected()));
  Serial.flush();

  if (!flag){
    Serial.print("Could not connect to server: ");
    Serial.println(host);
    Serial.println("Exiting...");
    Serial.flush();
    return;
  }

  // Data will still be pushed even certification don't match.
  if (client.verify(fingerprint, host)) {
    Serial.println("Certificate match.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Certificate mis-match");
  }

   Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter..");

  // Initialize the PulseOximeter instance
  // Failures are generally due to an improper I2C wiring, missing power supply
  // or wrong target chip
  if (!pox.begin()) {
    Serial.println("FAILED");
    for (;;);
  } else {
    Serial.println("SUCCESS");
  }

  pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);

}

// This is the main method where data gets pushed to the Google sheet
void postData(float temp, float bpm){
  if (!client.connected()){
    Serial.println("Connecting to client again..."); 
    client.connect(host, httpsPort);
  }
  String urlFinal = String("/macros/s/") + GScriptId + "/exec?temperature=" + String(temp) + "&bpm=" + String(bpm);
  client.printRedir(urlFinal, host, googleRedirHost);
}

// Continue pushing data at a given interval
void loop() {

  int analogValue = analogRead(A0);
  float millivolts = (analogValue/1024.0) * 3300; //3300 is the voltage provided by NodeMCU
  float celsius = millivolts/10;
//  Serial.print("in DegreeC=   ");
//  Serial.println(celsius);
//  // Post these information
//  Serial.println("/");
//  postData(celsius);
//  Serial.println("/");
//  delay (10000);
  // Make sure to call update as fast as possible
  pox.update();

  // Asynchronously dump heart rate and oxidation levels to the serial
  // For both, a value of 0 means "invalid"
  if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
    Serial.print("Heart rate:");
    float bpm = pox.getHeartRate();
    Serial.print(bpm);
//    Serial.print("bpm / SpO2:");
//    float spo2 = pox.getSpO2();
//    Serial.print(spo2);
//    Serial.println("%");
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = ");
    Serial.print(celsius);
    Serial.print("*C");
    postData(celsius, bpm);
    Serial.println();

    tsLastReport = millis();
}
}
```

I expect the code to write the temperature and heartbeat values into the formatted google sheets.

Google Sheets image

[image]

```
//Google script code

function doGet(e) { 
  Logger.log( JSON.stringify(e) );  // view parameters
  var result = 'Ok'; // assume success
  if (e.parameter == 'undefined') {
    result = 'No Parameters';
  }
  else {
    var sheet_id = 'sheetid';       // Spreadsheet ID
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet_id).getActiveSheet();     // get Active sheet
    var newRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;                        
    var rowData = [];
    rowData[0] = new Date();                                            // Timestamp in column A
    for (var param in e.parameter) {
      Logger.log('In for loop, param=' + param);
      var value = stripQuotes(e.parameter[param]);
      Logger.log(param + ':' + e.parameter[param]);
      switch (param) {
        case 'temperature': //Parameter
          rowData[1] = value; //Value in column B
          result = 'Written on column B';
          break;
        case 'bpm': //Parameter
          rowData[2] = value; //Value in column C
          result += ' ,Written on column C';
          break;  
        default:
          result = "unsupported parameter";
      }
    }
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rowData));
    // Write new row below
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1, rowData.length);
    newRange.setValues([rowData]);
  }
  // Return result of operation
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}
/**
* Remove leading and trailing single or double quotes
*/
function stripQuotes( value ) {
  return value.replace(/^["']|['"]$/g, "");
}
// End of file
```

Comment: Is there an associated Google Apps Script that is being sent the information?  We would need to see that code as well.

Comment: @Karl_S I have added the google script as well.

Comment: At a quick glance I would suggest trying `.getSheetByName(name)` as opposed to `.getActiveSheet()`

Comment: @Karl_S sorry for the late reply (busy with exams). I will try and implement the change and tell you what happens. Thanks in advance. But why does the value in the arduino serial plotter say 0 for heartbeat value??

Comment: Serial plotter in the Arduino meaning from the Arduino code serial monitor wouldv suggest you are not reading the sensor correctly.  I would post a question on that I'm the Arduino forum at https://forum.arduino.cc Are you using [this example](https://www.teachmemicro.com/max30100-arduino-heart-rate-sensor/) as your base? See if you can read other items from the sensor. If not, check the wiring.

Comment: @Karl_S Ok thanks. I will see what I can do. Thanks for helping me out.